# Can I download/access a full table of H3 Index (resolution 11) with the corresponding lat and long by using Python H3 library?

Tags: python, h3

I want to download a full table of H3 Index (resolution 11) with the corresponding lat and long of the United States by Python H3 library. I want to import the data table to my company's database and join it to our customer records.

I tried to look up the H3 package documentation and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

We don't offer downloadable data for H3, but you can calculate this yourself using `polyfill` (in H3v3) or `polygon_to_cells` (in H3v4). Res 11 is quite fine, so you'll probably want to polyfill each state or even each county separately, then add the resulting cells to the DB.